# Threejs Change Mesh Color doesn't get recognized

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have been trying to change the color of a mesh I created using PlaneGeometry and  MeshBasic Material.

```
var planeSegments = 20,
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.PlaneGeometry(horizon, horizon, planeSegments, planeSegments),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color:0xFFFFFF })
    );

plane.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
plane.position.y = 0;

planes.push(plane);
```

If I add this to MeshBasicMaterial object, it renders the wireframe with the current color. But I don't want the wireframe but a static color.

```
wireframe: true
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/exiara/mrwdrwkn/
It seems your code is working but maybe you need to rotate your plane to `-Math.PI/2` instead of just `Math.PI/2` . Otherwise you maybe looking at the plane from the backside.